# Detecting currently active window

Tags: linux, command-line, xorg

The linux commandline tool `wmctrl` allows you to list all windows, or all desktops, among other things. In the desktop-listing mode, the current desktop is marked with an asterisk.

I need a tool that can figure out the currently active window's title. Unfortunately, `wmctrl` doesn't have a helper that does this - despite it knowing which window is currently active (see `:ACTIVE:` marker).

Is there another commandline tool that can give me the window id and/or window title of the current window?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Install `xdotool`, then run

```
xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname
```

It will give e.g. for the current webpage opened in Firefox :

```
linux - Detecting currently active window - Super User - Mozilla Firefox
```

Comment: Powerful tool! Apart from getting current active window, it also has lots of other useful functionalities.

Comment: Compared to Jim Paris's answer, this has the disadvantage of a dependency to install, but it seems to run faster, particularly if xdotool is already in the disk cache.

Comment: If you want to manipulate the current window with `wmctrl`, you could do: `wmctrl -i -r \`xdotool getwindowfocus\` -e 0,10,10,-1,-1`, where `-i` tells wmctrl to expect the window id rather than the window title.

Answer (score 44):

This is more direct and only uses `xprop` and `cut`:

```
xprop -id $(xprop -root 32x '\t$0' _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -f 2) _NET_WM_NAME
```

---

These commands are just an extraction of properties from the root window and the application window, but per Lorenzo von Matterhorn's request:

- First,

  ```
  xprop -root 32x '\t$0' _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW
  ```

  Extracts the `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` property from the root, which
  gives you the XID of the active window.  The `32x '\t$0'` tells `xprop` to format the output in a way that `cut` can easily parse later.
- Then, extract just the XID from the output with `cut -f 2`
- Then, pass the XID in as a parameter to

  ```
  xprop -id XID _NET_WM_NAME
  ```

Which prints the name of that window.

Comment: hi there, can you please explain the arguments and a bit of the syntax? it may be helpful for the QA and future readers.

Answer (score 11):

#### There is, but no short answer or solution.

```
$ wmctrl -lp | grep $(xprop -root | grep _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | head -1 | \
    awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/,//' | sed 's/^0x/0x0/')
```

#### result:

```
0x03800004  0 16459  xxxxxxxxxx /bin/bash
```

#### In use:

```
$ for x in $(seq 1 10); do sleep 5; wmctrl -lp | grep $(xprop -root | \
    grep _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | head -1 | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/,//' | \
    sed 's/^0x/0x0/'); done

0x03800004  0 16459  xxxxxxxxxx /bin/bash
0x020000a4  0 13524  xxxxxxxxxx linux - Detecting currently active window - Super User - Mozilla Firefox (Build 20120129142219)
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, didn't know about the xprop utility. In the meantime, I've patched wmctrl to provide such an option and sent it to the author. Unfortunately, I didn't get a response yet.

Comment: +1 for effectiveness and "simplicity" on the code

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me:

`xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d ' ' -f 5) WM_NAME`

Gives:

`WM_NAME(STRING) = "~"`

So maybe you'd do a little sed ugliness to get the name all by itself:

`xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d ' ' -f 5) WM_NAME | sed -e 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/'`

Gives:

`~`

Which is my currently focussed window name, all by itself.

Or, avoid sed with the slightly less ugly:

`xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d ' ' -f 5) WM_NAME | awk -F '"' '{print $2}'`

Comment: Or since cut has laready been introduced, you could use that again: `xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d ' ' -f 5) WM_NAME | cut -d '"' -f 2`

Answer (score 5):

Relatively short, and handles window names containing quotes correctly:

```
xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d ' ' -f 5) WM_NAME | 
sed -nr 's/.*= "(.*)"$/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) to name your active window? This will provide the additional benefit of avoiding confusing situations where windows have duplicate names.

Just name the active window using:

```
wmctrl -r ':ACTIVE:' -N "your_unique_window_name"
```

And access it by the unique window name you've assigned it above.